# jQuery bvalidator Phone Number Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I'm using bValidator for form validation. Form fields are generated dynamically from a json file and loaded into an angularJS view on the fly.

I'm trying to validate a phone number input field using regex, I don't want user's to enter 9999999999 as phone number.Below is the regex expression

```
data-bvalidator="number,required,regex[\!(9999999999)]"
```

I also tried

```
data-bvalidator="number,required,regex[\^(9999999999)]"
```

and many others. But not getting the desired result

Comment: Can you add a snippet?

Comment: I think the order might count so try using :

`data-bvalidator="regex[\^(9999999999)],required,number"`

Comment: @R.Czq tried with different order , no luck

Comment: Then I would try to use another regex that you know for sure is correct. If not maybe you could try something like this:
`data-bvalidator="digit,minlength[10],maxlength[10],required"`